# Which Tools Can I Use To Create Characters Like This

Tags: 3d, character-design, character-styles

[image]

http://www.paladinstudios.com/wp-content/themes/paladin/images/arthur.png

Sub Question 1:- Can I create this in GIMP?

Sub Question 2:- Please also list down tools which can be used to create 3D characters like this and then I can take snaps of the character from different angles, like profile view, back view, top down view and at any custom angle.

Comment: You need 3d Software.. Gimp or anything Adobe makes won't do it.

Comment: You could draw it (2D) in Gimp, but you would have to re-illustrate each angle. This question will probably help: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/19794/how-should-i-get-started-if-i-want-to-work-as-a-3d-designer-for-games/19803#19803

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This character could be done in any 3D package such as:

- [Autodesk's Maya](http://www.autodesk.com/products/autodesk-maya/overview) - Some consider this as the standard for any 3D character modeling and character animation.
- [3dS Max](http://www.autodesk.com/products/autodesk-3ds-max/overview) - Also produced by Autodesk but is considered the standard for architectural models.
- [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) - Arguable one of the best opensource solutions for 3D modeling and one of the best character animation sequences known as [Big Buck Bunny](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YE7VzlLtp-4&feature=player_detailpage) was developed by the Blender Foundation.

  just to name a few.